# UX Process: What to do when first given a task?

Tags: design-process, process, team, collaboration, team-building

i’ve been doing some research on how to go about the UX process. Guides tend to show the full blown process which can take a long time and seem to require a certain level of organisational UX maturity.

Practically, as an in-house UX designer, what can the UX process look like when a task comes to you? I’m figuring this piece out so that i can better estimate time and task allocation to the team & to the PMs.

Comment: This question is a bit vague and difficult to answer, but perhaps you can provide some ideas about the type of team structure and delivery process that you follow, and the usual tasks that you are being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the task, generally you need to understand the constraints within which you are trying to generate an output (based on the input or information you are provided with).

The full end-to-end product delivery process encompasses more than just the user related research, design, prototyping and testing, but understanding the part that you play in the overall process helps you come to terms with what is within your responsibility and what falls outside of it (and therefore you need to work with or rely on other people for).

For more junior designers, usually the task will come to you with more specific constraints and specifications (e.g. update a UI component based on the current design system).

For more senior designers, often you will be given a task and be required to evaluate the feasibility and the implications of particular approaches, and be required to make decisions about it (e.g. should we do A or B or something else?). And based on your understanding of the delivery timeframe and resources available, you need to timebox your work and negotiate an output that the PMs or managers will be able to defend.